# How to ignore '\r' while counting characters of several files with wc -m

Tags: bash, git, carriage-return

I try to count characters that where submitted to git by the author "JohnJohnson" using this command:

```
wc -m $(git log --use-mailmap --no-merges --author="JohnJohnson" --name-only --pretty=format:"" | sort -u)
```

The problem is that on Linux and Windows(git-bash) it produces different results, at least because on Windows the new line consists of two chars '\r\n'. Is there a way to make wc -m to ignore '\r' so I get consistent results on both OSs with the same command?

Comment: Add output of `git ... | sort ...` without `wc -m $(...)` and your desired output to your question (no comment here).

Comment: do you know w/ 100% certainty that the only character you need to ignore is `\r`? do you need to worry about any differences due to locale/language settings?  I'd probably lean towards a function that loops through the given list of files performing a `tr -d '\r' | wc -m` on each file

Comment: @markp-fuso: `\r` is definitely the most problematic difference, maybe the only one - I'll see once I get rid of it. Do you have a one-liner for it? Also I need to get the total count...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** While running `dos2unix` on each file before running `wc -m` should suffice, I'm assuming a) `dos2unix` is not available and/or b) OP may find there are other characters (besides `\r`) that need to be removed.

---

Assuming the objective is to generate the *same exact output* as `wc -m`, one idea using a user-defined function:

```
my_wc () {
    local charcount=0 totcount=0

    for fname in $@
    do
        charcount=$(tr -d '\r' < $fname | wc -m)
        echo "$charcount $fname" 
        ((totcount+=charcount))
    done

    echo "$totcount total"
}
```

Applying to OP's example:

```
my_wc $(git log --use-mailmap --no-merges --author="JohnJohnson" --name-only --pretty=format:"" | sort -u)
```

If OP finds additional characters (besides `\r`) to skip then add them to the `tr -d '\r'` call).

---

Another function idea but this one uses `awk`:

```
my_wc() {
    awk 'BEGIN { RS="^$" }                  # whole file becomes one single, long record
               { gsub("\r","")
                 n=length($0)
                 tot+=n
                 print n,FILENAME
               }
         END   { print tot,"total"}' $@
}
```

---

Demonstrating these functions on a few sample files:

```
$ head f?
==> f1 <==
a       13
a       5
b       7
a       20
a       3

==> f2 <==
a       13
a       5
b       7
a       20
a       3

==> f3 <==
a       13
a       5
b       7
a       20
a       3

$ dos2unix f?

$ wc -m f?
22 f1
22 f2
22 f3
66 total

$ unix2dos f?

$ wc -m f?
27 f1
27 f2
27 f3
81 total

$ my_wc f?
22 f1
22 f2
22 f3
66 total
```

Answer (score 0):

Operate in a repo configured to do no newline translation in your work tree, i.e. with `eol` processing turned off. You can do this anywhere, say `git config core.eol false`. Easiest way to avoid interference is probably to do this in a scratch clone,

```
git clone -ns . `mktemp -d`; cd $_
git config core.eol false
git checkout
```

and now you've got a pristine checkout with no eol munging applied.

Comment: But will it be possible to view the files using Notepad? Will it not become one long line, if Windows native new lines disappear?

Comment: You could use an editor that's not confused by other newline conventions.

Comment: true. We actually use [SparkleShare](https://www.sparkleshare.org/) on Windows for syncing with the central git repo, so I doubt it will comply with `git config core.eol false`... Will it?